# To find mean of image using .PixelValues in regionprops using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to find out mean,`kurtosis`,`skew` etc of different connected regions seperately. May I found it using `.PixelValue` command using following code? or `.PixelValue` command to be used? Please help me.This is my first work.Please correct my code to find mean.
% Out is my region of interest output image.

```
[val num]=bwlabel(Out);    
STATS=regionprops(val,'All');    
for i=1:num
   kk=STATS(i);    
   kk1=kk.PixelList;
   % To find mean
   [r c]=size(kk1);    
   ax(i)=r*c;   
   pp(i)=sum(sum(kk1));    
   bx(i)=pp(i)/su;
   mean=bx(i);
end
```

Comment: I am really sorry.I dont know how to properly fomat code to post here

Comment: I've edited the code again, I think it makes more sense this way. Please fix it if it's wrong what I did.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're using `bwlabel`, which suggests `Out` is a binary image, so every non-zero pixel is going to have a value of 1. What is there to compute if all components contain pixels of value 1? Is `Out` actually a grayscale image? Are you trying to compute centroids?

Comment: 'out' is binary image.I also think about it but i think 'regionprops()' could be applied only on binary image. @Cris Luengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compute the mean of the pixel values of `a` within connected components of `Out`, then you want to do as follows (assuming `a` is a grey-value image):

```
lab = bwlabel(Out);
stats = regionprops(lab,a,'PixelValues');
```

and then, for each `stats.PixelValues`, compute the mean:

```
m = zeros(size(stats))
for ii = 1:numel(stats);    
     m(ii) = mean(stats(ii).PixelValues);
end
```

or more simply:

```
m = cellfun(@mean,{stats.PixelValues})
```

Note that `regionprops` can be called with a second input image, which contains the grey values. The `'PixelValues'` property is a list with pixel values for each connected component.

To further simplify the code, you can skip calling `bwlabel`, and directly pass the binary image to `regionprops`:

```
stats = regionprops(Out,a,'PixelValues');
```

Comment: My input image is 'a'.Its then thresholded,filtered,segmented,and from the segmented image region of interest calculated.image a alone is grey,remaining stages give binary as output image.So i think i have to calculate mean,standard deviation,skewness,kurtosis etc on image 'a',but how i could done it with regionprops.Please help if possible,I am struggling with this.

Comment: The second image passed to `regionprops` is a grey-value image. That is where the pixels are read from an put into `PixelValues`. I have edited the answer to include your image `a`.

Comment: I used following code to find standard deviation,skewness and kurtosis along with the code you given for finding mean.Please check whether it give correct results.Because  when  i run this code i am getting values,but not sure whether correct or not.Help me please

Comment: `m = zeros(size(stats));`                  
`for ii = 1:numel(stats); `                 
     `m(ii) = mean(stats(ii).PixelValues)`
     `s(ii) = std2(stats(ii).PixelValues)`
     `skewww(ii) = skewness(double(stats(ii).PixelValues))`
     `kurtooo(ii) = kurtosis(double(stats(ii).PixelValues))`
`end`

Comment: @Silpa: That sounds about right. You can use `std`, since `PixelValues` is a vector.

Comment: @Luengon: Thank You for your guidence

Comment: Please give me a support for this if possible:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839116/matlab-code-for-training-neural-network-for-classification